# File upload not working | Php

Tags: php, forms, file

I'm trying to upload a file in php and unable to do it. The file I'm trying to upload is a csv file, but it should not be a concern. I'm using php to upload my file. I'm also trying to process the form in the same page. Below is my code for file upload and it is not working...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="csv_file">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>


<?php   
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if(isset($_POST['csv_file'])) {             
            echo "<p>".$_POST['csv_file']." => file input successfull</p>";
            fileUpload();
        }
    }   

function fileUpload () {
    $target_dir = "var/import/";
    $file_name = $_FILES['csv_file']['name'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'];

    if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $target_dir.$file_name)) {
        echo "<h1>File Upload Success</h1>";            
    }
    else {
        echo "<h1>File Upload not successfull</h1>";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: `enctype = "multipat/form-data"` add it to `<form>`

Comment: it should be this -  **<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">**

Comment: Its `multipart` not `multipat`

Comment: As soon as I use enctype="multipart/form-data", nothing works at all the page simply refreshes. But, when I'm not using enctype="multipart/form-data", at least it prints File Upload not successfull.

Comment: @AbhishekDhanrajShahdeo  can you please check the codes given to you. check every  code and let us know whose code works for you?

Comment: I have tried all the codes and found that actual problem in my code was using $_POST for files while I should have been using $_FILES. All the codes mentioned below are working as I have tried them seperately. Now, I have found the actual problem and fix, but thanks to all for their answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have try below code and it's work perfect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>File Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="csv_file">
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>


        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            echo "<p>" . $_POST['csv_file'] . " => file input successfull</p>";
            $target_dir = "images ";
            $file_name = $_FILES['csv_file']['name'];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'];

            if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $target_dir . $file_name)) {
                echo "<h1>File Upload Success</h1>";
            } else {
                echo "<h1>File Upload not successfull</h1>";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if without file selection user hit the submit button then the above code will fails

Comment: add if condition file is exist or not.

Answer (score 4):

update your form code with enctype attribute

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="csv_file">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

use [enctype="multipart/form-data"](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="csv_file"> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>File Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="csv_file">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>


    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            if ($_FILES['csv_file']['size'] > 0)
            {
                echo "<p>".$_FILES['csv_file']['name']." => file input successfull</p>";

                fileUpload();
            }
        }

    function fileUpload () {
        $target_dir = "var/import/";
        $file_name = $_FILES['csv_file']['name'];


        $file_tmp = $_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'];

        if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $target_dir.$file_name)) {
            echo "<h1>File Upload Success</h1>";
        }
        else {
            echo "<h1>File Upload not successfull</h1>";
        }
    }

    ?>
</body>
```

> Below are the changes you need to make

- Add `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` in form tag as new attribute
- Change from this `if(isset($_POST['csv_file'])) {`  to this `if($_FILES['csv_file']['size'] > 0)  {` as you need to check size
  whether its uploaded or not
- Change from this `echo "<p>".$_POST['csv_file']." => file input
  successfull</p>";`  to this `echo "<p>".$_FILES['csv_file']['name']."
  => file input successfull</p>";`  as you need to use `$_FILES` to get file name instead of `$_POST`
- Last but not the least, complete `</body>` tag if you have not yet.

Answer (score 1):

Upload code in PHP[without checking its extension]

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
$path="var/import/";
$name = $_FILES['csv_file']['name'];//Name of the File
$temp = $_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($temp, $path . $name)){
    echo "success";
}else{
    echo "failed";
}
}
?>
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="csv_file">
<input type="submit" name="save" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
First Give permission to folder where you going to upload Ex: "var/import/" folder.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype= "multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="csv_file">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>


<?php   
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if(isset($_FILES['csv_file']) && $_FILES['csv_file']['size'] > 0) {             
            echo "<p>".$_FILES['csv_file']['name']." => file input successfull</p>";
            fileUpload();
        }
    }   

function fileUpload () {
    $target_dir = "var/import/";
    $file_name = $_FILES['csv_file']['name'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'];

    if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $target_dir.$file_name)) {
        echo "<h1>File Upload Success</h1>";            
    }
    else {
        echo "<h1>File Upload not successfull</h1>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for uploading files, the trick is enctype="multipart/form-data"
use this form definition